# T-SQL file into powershell script

Tags: sql, t-sql, powershell

I have a txt file(load_check_run_bmu.sql) that contains the following sql code.

```
RESTORE DATABASE Address from disk='C:\dir\path\address.bmu'

Use Client
GO
Select f_name
From
cst.name

USE wage
GO
Exec sp_salary

Use Client
GO
Select f_name
From
cst.name
```

I then have a batch file that contains:

```
sqlcmd -S .\NorthWind -i"C:\scripts\load_check_run_bmu.sql"
```

What I need to do is be able to execute all of necessary SQL commands in a powershell script and eliminate the sql txt file and the sqlcmd batch file

I'm aware I would need the following code, but I am struggling on how to convert the T-SQL script into something usable for the $SqlCmd.CommandText variable

```
$sqlServer = "."
$sqlDBName = "NorthWind"
$sqlConnectionString ="Server = $sqlServer; Database = $sqlDBName;     Integrated Security = True"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $sqlConnectionString
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
**$SqlCmd.CommandText = [SQL Command(s)]<====( Need assistance populating this)**
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlCmd.Connection.Open()
$ReturnValue = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$SqlCmd.Connection.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `T-SQL` `.txt` file into a string using double quotes `"` and take out the `GO` statements. You can also end each statement with `;` to ensure queries do not get mixed up and the queries should run without failure:

```
$TSQLString = "RESTORE DATABASE Address from disk='C:\dir\path\address.bmu';

Use Client;
Select f_name
From
cst.name;

USE wage;
Exec sp_salary;

Use Client;
Select f_name
From
cst.name;"
```

Then use the string for your variable:

```
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $TSQLString
```

It also looks like you using multiple databases in the query above. If this is the case this approach might not work has you are connecting to a *single* database with the statement below.

```
$sqlConnectionString ="Server = $sqlServer; Database = $sqlDBName; Integrated Security=True"
```

To get round this you will need to open up a connection for each statement. So you might want to make a function that connects to a server\database and runs a given query e.g (Run-Sql would be the function you need to create).

```
$SQLQuery1 = "RESTORE DATABASE Address from disk='C:\dir\path\address.bmu';"
$SQLQuery2 = "Select f_name From cst.name;"
$SQLQuery3=  "Exec sp_salary;"
$SQLQuery4 = "Select f_name From cst.name;"

# Run all statments
Run-SQL -query $SQLQuery1 -DB "NorthWind" -Server "." 
Run-SQL -query $SQLQuery2 -DB "Client"    -Server "." 
Run-SQL -query $SQLQuery3 -DB "wage"      -Server "." 
Run-SQL -query $SQLQuery4 -DB "Client"    -Server "."
```

Comment: What about the "Go" statements.  I understand that this is a batch separator in T-SQL and not a valid sql command.

So how can the "GO" statements be handled so that there are no errors produced and the necessary results are achieved?

Comment: What error are you getting? GO is a command recognized by the `sqlcmd` and `osql` utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188037.aspx - See the remarks section. And are you running `SQL Server 2008` and up?

Comment: Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'."
At C:\temp\test.ps1:47 char:9
+         $ReturnValue = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Answer (score -1):

Use invoke-SQLCMD
Whick is part of sqlps module